# Move to a Div/ID from Navbar Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, So I have a navbar that, when a link is clicked, I want it to move to a specific div (i.e. when clicking the "About" link, the page moves to the About section of the page).

A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stx1ypbr/1/) of the Code in question:

HTML in question:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-lg sticky-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">David Madrigal's Portfolio</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The plan is to add classes that would match the id names of the parts of the page I want to go to.

Here is the JS I have so far:

```
function main() {
$
$('.nav-item').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Note, I am using Bootstrap 4.0. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "move to a specific div" you mean to scroll to that position, right?

Comment: Correct, sorry if I wan't clear enough. :/

Comment: Your anchor tags is doing that for you...The reason it is not working is because you haven't applied any id to any elements for the anchor tag to jump to

Comment: Got it. Ill test it out when im able to get back to my computer,  and update if it worked...

Comment: So update: the adding of id tags worked, except for the Projects link, which seems to be a little picky for some reason, unless I'm completely missing something. And I also want to implement a smooth scroll for them, but not sure how to use the .animate() property in JS (which seems to be the correct way to do it as I gather from other posts on this site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with smooth scrolling (the jquery slim libs does not support the animate property)
Snippet below

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
  if (target.length) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5dc;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(imgs/los-angeles-skyline.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#bootstrap-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#bootstrap-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #014c8c;
}

#info-cards {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#card-blocks {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card-button {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#form-container {
  border: 5px solid rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.4);
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.form-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #292b2c !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-lg sticky-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">David Madrigal's Portfolio</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Welcome!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a site to which I will be adding all of my website works.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>This site uses <a href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/" id="bootstrap-link">Bootstrap 4</a> to make the site visually pleasing.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="About">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 div.md-12" id="info-cards About">
      <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header">About the <strong>Developer</strong></h3>
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="media">
            <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/17634751?v=3&u=764e15995bb82b2f37a3bdb15ba59e11f038a2f1&s=400" alt="githubProfilePic">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h5 class="mt-0">Welcome to My Portfolio!</h5>
              Hello there! This is a personal portfolio of all of my works will be open source and can be changed however you please. Just make sure to provide links to the frameworks used so others can create projects with them!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="card-blocks projects projects">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Block #1
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Featured: "Just Random Musing..."
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">My First Site W/ Bootstrap!</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="https://mexdave1997.github.io/Just-Random-Musings/" class="btn btn-outline-primary card-button">View the Site!</a>
          <a href=https://github.com/MEXdave1997/Just-Random-Musings "" class="btn btn-outline-info card-button">View Source!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Block #2
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="skillbars">
  <div class="card">
    <h3 class="card-header">Featured Skills</h3>
    <div class="card-block">
      <p class="card-text">HTML</p>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 95%" aria-valuenow="95" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">95%</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p class="card-text">CSS</p>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 85%" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">85%</div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p class="card-text">JavaScript</p>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 65%" aria-valuenow="65" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">65%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form class="container-fluid" id="contact">
  <div id="form-container">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="InputName" class="col-4 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="InputName" aria-described-by="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter Name" />
        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Please enter your Full Name (First and Last)</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="InputEmail" class="col-4 col-form-label">Email Address</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" aria-described-by="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email" />
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We will never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-4 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<footer class="footer text-muted">
  <p>&copy 2017. David Madrigal-Hernandez.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was hoping for. The only thing that doesn't seem to be working is the Project tab, though I may be overlooking something there. Ill try to modify that a bit, see if I can fix this.

Comment: Ok, so update: All I needed to do to get the project tab to work is to move the id from the div with the container-fluid class to the div with the row class. so the code would look this this: 

    <div class="container-fluid" id="card-blocks">
      <div class="row" id="projects">
      ....
      </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

You missed the Id, just add an Id in the section container, for your case:

`<div class="container-fluid" id="About">`

since in your anchor you are jumping to `#About`

`<a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a>`

Comment: OK, that worked. And to add the smooth scroll, what can I do? I've tried to use the .animate() property, but i can never get it working. Also, I added the corresponding ID tags, but the projects one is the only one that seems to not want to work. The site is [here](https://mexdave1997.github.io/bootstrap_4.0_site/).

Comment: From your jsFiddle, you are using the slim build of jQuery, which doesn't include most of the library. Therefore you should be using the full version.
And for the Projects one, you cannot contain space in the ID, consider using `class` instead.
Feel free to mark this as answer if it helps you.

Comment: so, the href would be `href=".Projects"` instead of `href="#Projects"`? Also, thanks for the first comment, completely overlooked that... :/